# Bootstrap col-xs-6 is not giving me a 2 column layout

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am not sure what seems to be the issue with my code ... I believe it to be correct but for some reason I am unable to get `col-xs-6` to give me 2 columns... when my grid gets to that break point they behave as if I was using `col-xs-12` and all stacking on top of each other... This is what my div looks like

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
```

They all behave as expected except `col-xs-6` which I would expect would give me a two column layout...

Here is a link to the site I am developing: http://cbshuttle.staging.wpengine.com/

The section I am trying to trouble shoot is the hotel logos near the bottom that I want to be in 2 columns when the site gets to the xs break point... Any insight would be much appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: I just tried it on Chrome Windows 10 and I correctly see two columns when I make my browser really small.

Comment: yes I had to manually add the links to the bootstrap CSS in order to make it behave as expected... I did not realize the Avada theme integration of bootstrap was not the standard bootstrap css their bootstrap integration is not fully functional only partially... but after adding the links to the real bootstrap CSS It started working!

Answer (score 0):

The Avada theme you're using intentionally modifies Bootstrap to eliminate the "extra small" screen size.  While Bootstrap treats 0-767px as extra small and 768-991px as small, Avada treats all sizes below 992px as "small" and uses the "col-sm-*" layout.

If I replace your Avada `style.min.css` stylesheet with a real version of `bootstrap.css`, I get two-column layout at extra small sizes, as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback... still trying to figure out all the quirks with the avada theme... I will give it a shot!